# Using baby powder on Yom Kippur

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, inuy-affliction

**Is one permitted to use baby powder**-or talcum powder, Gold Bond, etc- **on Yom Kippur**? (either for themselves or for a child)

### OR

Would it be forbidden since it could be akin to "annointing oneself" ([**SA**, Orach Chaim 614:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.614.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) or perhaps "washing for pleasure" ([**SA**, Orach Chaim 613:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.613.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))?

Comment: There may be other problems that may be related to some type of *melacha* akin to a Shabbat prohibition. I can't think of it, offhand, and you don't seem to be concerned about that in this Q. As for "anointing", first of all, I think this refers to beautification and cosmetics, mainly, as far as I know. I think powder to soothe a rash or prevent sweat, etc. is not "anointing". Second, the baby, who is not yet obligated in *inuy* (affliction), I believe, would be exempt from such concerns, assuming there are any.

Comment: Can whomever VTC because of "psak" explain how you see this, here?

Answer (score 5):

Rav Moshe Feinstien Zt'l opinion is quoted in רשומי אהרן ח"ב או"ח סי' תרי"ד אות א that it is permitted in a case of need as baby powder is not considered anointing.

As usual consult a Rabbi for a final Halachic ruling.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any proper sources, but I found a number of online rulings that it's permitted:

https://helpfulhalacha.blogspot.com/2008/10/laws-of-yom-kippur.html

> It’s forbidden to use deodorants on Yom Kippur, but is permitted before Yom Kippur. (Talcum Powder is ok)

https://images.shulcloud.com/191/uploads/-ALL-SR/ECDPLawsofYomimNoraimandSukkos.pdf

> using baby powder to remove a bad odor is permitted

https://www.toraland.org.il/18649

> פיזור טלק אינו להנאה אלא למניעת/הרגעת גרוי ולכן הוא מותר

https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/96303

> האם מותר לפזר אבקת טלק באיזור המפשעה ביום כיפור כדי למנוע גירודים ושפשפות? ... מותר